# Considerations when using Function name as a variable

Tags: vba

In VBA, you *can* treat a UDF name just like a `Dim`med variable. For example

```
Function ADD(a, b) As Long
ADD = a
ADD = ADD + b
End Function
```

Where `ADD` stores the intermediate value as well as the end result. My question is; in terms of what's going on behind the scenes, **is there any difference between storing a number/piece of data in a standard variable vs a function name variable.**

---

I worry that perhaps the routine that called the function gets an update whenever the variable changes if you use the function name, rather than only when `End Function` is executed. IE. if you have some code

```
answer = ADD(1, 2)
```

then in memory `answer` gets written to twice, once when `ADD = a`, once when `ADD = ADD + b`. Of course we don't see this, because answer is left with whatever the final `ADD` value is

I ask because I often find I build up a function answer in stages using an intermediate variable, then pass that to the function name itself, where instead I could just write directly to the function name.

E.g.

```
Function ADD(a, b) As Long
Dim tot As Long
tot = a
tot = tot + b
ADD = tot
End Function
```

vs the first example. They acheive the same thing, in the second example `tot` represents the formula result, and so we need a final `ADD = tot` line at the end. For speed I would like to reduce any writes that are made, so is there any drawback *in terms of speed, not readability* to using the first method as opposed to declaring intermediates?

NB, to clarify, that's not all intermediates, I just mean the single intermediate that represents the function result, and could be replaced by the function name in the code.

Comment: @CallumDA, why the tag edits - I don't think this is necessarily to do with Excel, was it just to attract the right sort of attention?

Comment: Yep, feel free to remove them if you don't agree though.

Comment: Well I've already found one consideration; if the function returns an array, then trying to set an element of that array looks the same as trying to call the function! VBA didn't like that

Comment: With a million calls to the first function, I spend ~157 ms and to the second -  ~150ms. And everytime a second function is a winner by ~5ms (tested without recursion).

Comment: Related: [Best Way to Return a Value from a Function](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/274786/146810)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In speed the first method should be slightly faster - you declare one variable less (but I doubt that someone would be able to notice it).

In general, using the first method can bring you to a recursion, if you are not careful (or if you are a VBA beginner):

```
Option Explicit

Dim lng10 As Long

Public Sub Test()

    lng10 = 0
    Debug.Print ADD2(1, 1)

End Sub

Function ADD2(a As Long, b As Long) As Long

    lng10 = lng10 + 1
    ADD2 = a + b

    If lng10 < 10 Then
        ADD2 = ADD2 + ADD2(1, 1)
    End If

End Function
```

And if the recursion does not have a bottom, it would go to an overflow error.
With other words, this would be an runtime error:

```
Option Explicit

Dim lng10 As Long

Public Sub Test()

    lng10 = 0
    Debug.Print ADD2(1, 1)

End Sub

Function ADD2(a As Long, b As Long) As Long

    lng10 = lng10 + 1
    ADD2 = ADD2(a, b)

End Function
```

Comment: Debugging through that first one looks very weird

Comment: @Greedo - concerning the first snippet of code, it is strange/weird, because the results of the recursive function are kept in a stack and at the end they are used for the calculation. If you "translate" the code to C#, in visual studio this would be visible in the `Call Stack`.